# Select, default value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hey I have problem with set default value in select problem is started when I set inside array objects. How can I fix this problem??

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="select" ng-controller="checking">
  <select ng-model="lala" ng-options="item.name for item in arrayName">
  </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('select', []);

app.controller('checking', ($scope)=> {
  $scope.arrayName = [{'name':'first'}, {'name':'second'}, {'name':'third'}]; 
  $scope.lala = "first";
});
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/EbvGzv?editors=1111

Comment: Please include the code in the question next time, links to code are fine to support the question but if that link were to die this question would lose all context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change your [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to include a [`select as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)

```
<select ng-model="lala" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in arrayName">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('select', []);

app.controller('checking', function($scope) {
  $scope.arrayName = [{
    'name': 'first'
  }, {
    'name': 'second'
  }, {
    'name': 'third'
  }];

  $scope.lala = 'first';

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="select" ng-controller="checking">

  <select ng-model="lala" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in arrayName"></select>
  
  <p>Value of lala: <b>{{lala}}</b></p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below example you have to change array bit

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v for v in prop.values">
    </select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
{
    $scope.prop = 
    {
        "type": "select", 
        "name": "Service",
        "value": "first", 
        "values": ['first','second','third'] 
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: so, if I want have default value in select, I can have only if parameter object is equall parameter object or variable equall variable yes?

Comment: if I want default value Its can be only when I have parameter in object and this second value is in object too yes?

Comment: You can use like  "value": "" if you dont want to select default value

Comment: can u give me example??

Comment: Like this $scope.prop = 
 {
  "type": "select", 
  "name": "Service",
  "value": "", 
  "values": ['first','second','third'] 
 };

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve it by using `ng-init` as below

```
<div ng-app="select" ng-controller="checking">

  <select ng-init="lala = arrayName[0]" ng-model="lala" ng-options="item.name for item in arrayName"  >


  </select>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('select', []);

    app.controller('checking', ($scope)=> {
      $scope.arrayName = [{'name':'first'}, {'name':'second'}, {'name':'third'}]; 
      $scope.lala = "first";
    });
<script>
```

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOvLJo) example and hope it will help.

Comment: Using ng-init for this is not recommended by the documentation and is considered bad practice (even though it works!) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: You don't even need `ng-init` here, you could just do `$scope.lala = $scope.arrayName[0]` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to assign the ng-model like this.

```
 $scope.lala = $scope.arrayName[0];
```

Here is your codepen [link](https://codepen.io/thanveer/pen/dZzLwe)

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('select', []);

app.controller('checking', ($scope)=> {
  $scope.arrayName = [{'name':'first'}, {'name':'second'}, {'name':'third'}]; 
  $scope.lala = $scope.arrayName[0].name;
});
```

Comment: My recommendation trying this way.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**